# How can we get the previous formula field value in the next row formula field?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

I have two formula field Like Open balance and Closing balance.
In this, the Opening balance value will Previous day's Closing balance. 
And the Closing Balance Calculation will be done using the Open Balance value. 
For example the formula's inside the formula fields are:

> For Opening Balance

```
            If OnFirstRecord = true Then (If {OpenBalanceCreditAmount}=0 then {OpenBalanceDebitAmount} else if {OpenBalanceDebitAmount}=0 then (-{OpenBalanceCreditAmount}))else Previous({@ClosingBalAmount})
```

> For Closing Balance

```
    (If {@OpenBalanceAmount}<0 then ((-{@CreditAmount}+{@OpenBalanceAmount})+{@DebitAmount}) else if {@OpenBalanceAmount}>=0 then (({@DebitAmount}+{@OpenBalanceAmount})+(-{@CreditAmount})))
```

I am getting a error: "A Formula Cannot refer to itself,either directly or Indirectly".

Also I tried passing a temporary Formula field, which passes value of Closing balance to Open Balance. But,it too shown a same error. I think so referencing issue. Can we take only the value of closing balance by leaving the parameters used in Closing balance calculation.

Please help me out of this. And Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your formula again probably you missed bracket. try to intend your formula then you can easily find it.

Comment: What is the " -" next to {@CreditAmount}